# Android - check internet and Wi-Fi connectivity with the help of BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-wifi, android-broadcast

I want to check internet and Wi-Fi connectivity. I have implemented the code. But in this code the problem is, when I activate Wi-Fi in my device then it continuously toasts "Wi-Fi disconnected" and "Internet Connected" 3-4 times and then at last times it toasts "Wi-Fi connected" and then my Wi-Fi connection appears enabled in my device. I need to check Wi-Fi connection only once when I enable or disable Wi-Fi.
Thanks.

**Java**

```
public class ConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        boolean isConnectedInternet = 
                intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

        ConnectivityManager wifiConn = 
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo mWifi = wifiConn.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        if (mWifi.isConnected()) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi Conected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if(isConnectedInternet){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connection Lost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

**Menifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<receiver android:name=".ConnectionReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have my connection you can use it..

```
      public class ConnectionDetector {
        private Context _context;
        public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        }

        public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null)
        {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
            if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
                return true;
             }

        }
        return false;
        }
}
```

and in your activity..

```
if (new ConnectionDetector(this).isConnectingToInternet()){
         Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi Conected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it exactly, but it could be, that you receive all the events one time (CONECTIVITY_CHANGE, WIFI_STATE_CHANGED and STATE_CHANGE). For my understanding CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE should be enough. You should read detailed information in the dev doc.

Remove these two lines from your manifest:

```
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
```

Have a look at the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Comment: Just remove the intent-filters for the other two.